# JPA(OpenJPA) is very slow when searching on multiple data sources

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb, openjpa

We have an Spring application running on OpenJPA/Oracle. It has three persistenceUnit to take care of, but all three are on the same oracle instance so every unit has transaction-type as "RESOURCE_LOCAL".

The problem is, when performing a search using very basic `finder` meithod, like search employee by department(not a primary key, also not indexed but the employee table only owns a thousand record), it takes very long time to respond for result. The same query only take like 0.089 second on SQLplus. Hence open this thread to discuss what could be the main cause of the issue and what could be a possible solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Enable logging to see what happens at the JPA level. Then you can troubleshoot.

Comment: Without looking at code, it's difficult. Thousand around records shouldn't be a issue.